# How to merge two PlotItems into one csv file?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Is it possible to merge two plot items and export them as one csv file? I'm using pyqtgraph to visualise two graphs with common x axis whilst the y-axes are different. I can export them separately as two csv files but I would like to have only one csv file. Thanks in advance.

```
def export_CSV(self):
 exp1 = pg.exporters.CSVExporter(self.plot_data1)
 exp2 = pg.exporters.CSVExporter(self.plot_data2)
   
 exp1.export('Data1.csv')
 exp2.export('Data2.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a built-in exporter. You have to create Your own based on csv one.
Here is an example how You can do it.
It takes list of plots as a input and merge all curves into one csv file.

```
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from pyqtgraph import PlotItem
from pyqtgraph.exporters import CSVExporter


class MergedCSVExporter(CSVExporter):
    Name = "Merged CSV from plot data"

    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
        super().__init__(items[0])

    def export(self, fileName=None):
        data = []
        header = []
        i = 0

        for item in self.items:
            if not isinstance(item, PlotItem):
                raise Exception("Must have a PlotItem selected for CSV export.")

            if fileName is None:
                self.fileSaveDialog(filter=["*.csv", "*.tsv"])
                return

            appendAllX = self.params['columnMode'] == '(x,y) per plot'

            for c in item.curves:
                cd = c.getData()
                if cd[0] is None:
                    continue
                data.append(cd)
                if hasattr(c, 'implements') and c.implements('plotData') and c.name() is not None:
                    name = c.name().replace('"', '""') + '_'
                    xName, yName = '"' + name + 'x"', '"' + name + 'y"'
                else:
                    xName = 'x%04d' % i
                    yName = 'y%04d' % i
                if appendAllX or i == 0:
                    header.extend([xName, yName])
                else:
                    header.extend([yName])
                i += 1

            if self.params['separator'] == 'comma':
                sep = ','
            else:
                sep = '\t'

        with open(fileName, 'w') as fd:
            fd.write(sep.join(map(str, header)) + '\n')
            i = 0
            numFormat = '%%0.%dg' % self.params['precision']
            numRows = max([len(d[0]) for d in data])
            for i in range(numRows):
                for j, d in enumerate(data):
                    # write x value if this is the first column, or if we want
                    # x for all rows
                    if appendAllX or j == 0:
                        if d is not None and i < len(d[0]):
                            fd.write(numFormat % d[0][i] + sep)
                        else:
                            fd.write(' %s' % sep)

                    # write y value
                    if d is not None and i < len(d[1]):
                        fd.write(numFormat % d[1][i] + sep)
                    else:
                        fd.write(' %s' % sep)
                fd.write('\n')


MergedCSVExporter.register()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget_1 = pg.PlotWidget()
    p1 = pg.PlotCurveItem([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    widget_2 = pg.PlotWidget()
    p2 = pg.PlotCurveItem([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

    widget_1.addItem(p1)
    widget_2.addItem(p2)

    # Merge two plots
    exp1 = MergedCSVExporter([widget_1.plotItem, widget_2.plotItem])
    exp1.export("./out.csv")
```